# JSLint string comparison error Expected '===' and instead saw '=='

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am using this code in JSLint

```
var string = "Hello";
if (string == "Hello") {
    string = "World";
}
```

And I am getting this error

```
Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
if (string == "Hello") {
```

Why JSLint is throwing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From JSLint [docs](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) under **== and !=**

> The == and != operators do type coercion before comparing. This is bad
>   because it causes ' \t\r\n' == 0 to be true. This can mask type
>   errors. JSLint cannot reliably determine if == is being used
>   correctly, so it is best to not use == and != at all and to always use
>   the more reliable === and !== operators instead.
>
> If you only care that a value is truthy or falsy, then use the short
>   form. Instead of
>
> (foo != 0)
>
> just say
>
> (foo)
>
> and instead of
>
> (foo == 0)
>
> say
>
> (!foo)
>
> There is an eqeq option that allows the use of == and !=.

How to tell JSLint not to throw this error.

Use JSLint directive ***eqeq***

like this

```
/*jslint eqeq: true*/
```

So the full code will look like

```
/*jslint eqeq: true*/
var string = "Hello";
if (string == "Hello") {
    string = "World";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because JSLint thinks `==` should never be used (the equality system is *kind of* weird).

My advice is to learn how `==` and `===` work, and how they compare ([check the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3)). *Then*, you can make the best decision yourself instead of simply tagging a language construct with *never use it*.

Comment: Yes, there is difference between == and === but still == is valid in many conditions.